# Which of these two is the best way to handle try-catches for closing ResultSet, PreparedStatement, and Connection in a DAO class that uses JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, exception, dao

I am creating a DAO class that uses JDBC and MySQL. I have not received any indications on how to close the items listed in the title, but I read that it is good practice to do so. Now I thought this should be done in every CRUD method, but handling the exceptions seems a little artificial and I'm undecided about how to implement it.

First example:

```
public boolean update2(Dto dto) {
    assert dto != null;
    if (readById(dto.getId()).getId() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Row with this id doesn't exist");
    }
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        Connection connection = DAOFactory.createConnection();
        String sql = "SQL statement"; 
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            try {
                // Some stuff with preparedstatement
                ps.executeUpdate();
                flag = true;
            } finally {
                if (ps != null) ps.close();
            }
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Second example:

```
public boolean update(Dto dto) {
    assert dto != null;
    if (readById(dto.getId()).getId() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Row with this id doesn't exist");
    }
    boolean flag = false;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DAOFactory.createConnection();
        String sql = "SQL statement"; 
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        // Some stuff with preparedstatement
        ps.executeUpdate();
        flag = true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

In the second example i need duplicate exception handling. The first solution seems more clever to me, but I'm not sure it's more readable than the second one.

Are there conventions to be adopted for design that are not only subjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 1.7 and above, you can use [**try with resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to simplify the closing of resources. Provided that the resources implement the `AutoClosable` interface, which is the case for `Connection` and `PreparedStatement`, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
public boolean update2(String dto) {
    assert dto != null;

    if (readById(dto.getId()).getId() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Row with this id doesn't exist");
    }

    boolean flag = false;
    String sql = "SQL statement";
    try (Connection connection = DAOFactory.createConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.executeUpdate();
        flag = true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: This construct is much more readable and I did not know it, thank you very much.
However, I did not understand if, for versions older than 1.7, the choice falls on the developer or if there is a convention to be adopted.

Comment: Then use the second option; that is what I would prefer because the code is a bit cleaner that the first one.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would handle the `ClassNotFoundException` and maybe also `SQLException` more aggressively, e.g. wrapping them in a runtime exception, because these are almost always caused by deployment/programming errors (or problems with data/DB) from which you cannot recover.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Sure. My answer was about how to close resources neatly. I am 100% by you; exceptions should not be printed out to the console in a production environment. I just wanted to mention about it too, but forgot. Thanks, a good point.